# Using the ruby SDK, how can I get an SSL certificate signed for my AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a pem and crt file to use with my EC2 instance on AWS. I have 2 questions here:

1) The configuration instructions say: "Normally, at this stage you would submit your CSR to a Certificate Authority (CA) to apply for a digital server certificate." To whom do I send the certificate and how do I do it? Sorry, first time for me.

2) I am horribly confused about the uploading process to AWS. I have seen articles on uploading to a load balancer and uploading to IAM. I am using an EC2 instance and not, as far as I know a "load balancer" and I do not use IAM security. So how should I upload and what do I need to do?

Yours very confused seeking help ...

Comment: This is a server administration task, with no AWS-specific mechanism.  You don't do this any differently with an EC2 instance than you would do it with any other ordinary server.

Comment: Thanks I don't know how to do it anyway. So to whom should I send the certificate or does it happen automatically? Sorry but I am lost here.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get an SSL certificate signed you need to submit it to a trusted company, known as a Certificate Authority (CA).  Think of your CSR like a blank cheque, nobody will trust it until it's signed by someone trustworthy.

There are commercial CAs which vary greatly in price, alternatively there are free CAs such as [CACert](http://www.cacert.org/) (which I haven't used).  The general process is: upload your CSR to the CA's site & the CA will provide a signed certificate.

If you want more information on what a CA's role is wikipedia is a great place to start, excerpt below:

> In cryptography, a certificate authority or certification authority (CA) is an entity that issues digital certificates. A digital certificate certifies the ownership of a public key by the named subject of the certificate. This allows others (relying parties) to rely upon signatures or on assertions made by the private key that corresponds to the certified public key. In this model of trust relationships, a CA is a trusted third party – trusted both by the subject (owner) of the certificate and by the party relying upon the certificate. Many[quantify] public-key infrastructure (PKI) schemes feature CAs.

2. For serving SSL traffic you have two options:

   - A common web pattern is to "Terminate SSL at the load balancer", which just means the load balancer will host and serve the SSL certificate, then simply sends traffic to the web server (your EC2 instance) via http.  This is generally considered safe as the last hop is within your infrastructure.
   - If you want to go without a load balancer you'll need something on the EC2 instance to serve the SSL certificate.  Here again there are plenty of options but generally installing Nginx or Apache on your instance to sit in front of your app works well.

Example configuration for Apache & Nginx are plenty & you should be able to find specific instructions for what-ever language & framework you're using but they're all fairly similar.

The [play framework doco](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/HTTPServer) has examples for both Apache & Nginx sitting in front of a web app running on the same (EC2) server on port 9000 which should work for pretty much anything running on that port.

Plenty of reading to get you on your way, hope it helps!